# How to remove authentication of jbpm kie-server

Tags: jboss, jbpm, bpmn, kie-server

I want to remove the authentication of user for kie-server. For this I have tried to remove the below mentioned configuration from the `web.xml` file

```
  <security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
      <web-resource-name>REST web resources</web-resource-name>
      <url-pattern>/services/rest/*</url-pattern>
      <http-method>GET</http-method>
      <http-method>PUT</http-method>
      <http-method>POST</http-method>
      <http-method>DELETE</http-method>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
      <role-name>kie-server</role-name>
      <role-name>user</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
  </security-constraint>
```

```
//from above config removed this portion
    <auth-constraint>
      <role-name>kie-server</role-name>
      <role-name>user</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
```

```
  <login-config>
    <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
    <realm-name>KIE Server</realm-name>
  </login-config>
```

Now server is starting but not able to see the task/claim/start/finish task

So where should I modify the configurations so that I can use the kie-server server without login. And want to perform operations based on groups.

Answer (score 1):

You see, task service is a separate module in kie. In that sense, it is wise to make an autologin then to chase all the places that inherit authentication.